# C++ Class Initalization

Tags: c++

I'm a python programmer who sees a lot of C++ code but doesn't know the language and there seems to be two ways to initalize a class. I was hoping that someone can tell me the difference.

```
class Point {
        int x, y;
     public:
        int get_x();
        int get_y();
        Point(int, int);
}

// ok we are going to leave the methods and constructors unimplemented for brevity
// now here's the part that puzzles me
Point p(5, 5); // ..or
Point p = new Point(5, 5);
```

What's the diffrence between the two?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of those variables lives on the stack, the other on the heap. The correct syntax is this:

```
Point p(5, 5); 
Point* p = new Point(5, 5);
```

The first one creates an object on the stack. When p goes out of scope, it'll be removed automatically. The second, creates a point object on the heap. Until you remove it manually, it'll remain in memory.

In the second case, p is a pointer to the Point object, while in the first case p *is* the point object.

Python essentially does only the second version and doesn't do the first. Python is garbage collected, so it'll also remove the point object from memory if it is no longer referenced.

However, I should mention (see comments) that the prefered method to create objects on the heap is to use smart pointers. See [DeadMG's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/157507/47555) for more details.

Comment: You forgot to mention that he forgot a `*`. Also, you *must* mention all the smart pointer things.

Comment: @DeadMG I corrected his syntax: "The correct syntax is this"...

Comment: The important part was the smart pointer stuff.

Comment: The "Don't answer his question just tell him more about smart pointers!" crowd is back and louder than ever.

Comment: @DeadMG that's not what he's asking. It's a simple question, and smart pointers aren't going to help anyone understand C++ right now.

Comment: Really? Why not? They are *much more important* than raw `new` in every conceivable fashion and you *must* know them to use heap memory safely

Comment: @Oleksi: To understand C++ you need to understand that you should never have owning raw pointers.

Comment: Downvoted because raw pointers are bad style in modern C++. You do not teach about dealing with legacy code to a beginner. Plus, automatic memory management is going to make a lot more sense to a Python programmer, where objects are ref-counted.

Comment: The question is explicitly about the differences between the two, not about the best practices in C++. Why don't we just start talking about RAII as well while we're here. I am not condoning using raw pointers. I am answering the question

Comment: We are. The difference is that one of them should *never, ever be used, by anyone, ever* - a fact which your answer fails to mention.

Comment: Edited to mention that smart pointers are the preferred method to create objects on the heap.

Comment: +1 for answering the question that was asked instead of going off on a diatribe.

Comment: @DeadMG, a smart pointer is an abstraction, and abstractions always "leak". The OP does not know C++, or what a pointer is. He is looking at some code, and he is trying to understand what it does. Talking about smart pointers in this context does not help him understand the code he is looking at, and is likely to confuse him even more.

Comment: SmartPointers are a crutch. Value objects that manage their memory are much easier to use and reason about.

Comment: "Downvoted because raw pointers are bad style in modern C++.": I am a C++ programmer and I do not use raw pointers that often, but I do not understand when I read that raw pointers are bad style in modern C++: if they were, why haven't they been removed from the language? They are probably still there because they have some use (maybe for some low-level, highly optimized programming?). Otherwise your are basically saying that C++ is carrying along some old-fashioned, useless and dangerous feature that people should avoid (and therefore it is a badly designed language).

Answer (score -3):

```
Point p(5, 5); // ..or
```

Creates an automatic variable "on the stack". This means that it's lifetime and memory is fixed to it's scope.

```
Point* p = new Point(5, 5);
```

Creates a memory leak, double delete, or heap corruption in your program. This means that it almost certainly will crash your program, cause it to corrupt user data, or other *fun* side effects. Which is why actual C++ programmers use alternatives, such as...

```
auto p = make_unique<Point>(5, 5);
```

Creates a Point "on the heap". In this case, it's lifetime and memory is fixed to the lifetime of the *owning* `unique_ptr<Point>`. This ownership can be transferred by move semantics. Unfortunately, `make_unique` is not provided as Standard (a known defect) but it's relatively easy to roll your own. It is a simple factory function.

```
auto p = std::make_shared<Point>(5, 5);
```

Also creates a Point "on the heap". In this case, it's lifetime and memory is fixed to the lifetime of *each* `shared_ptr<Point>` that points to it. When they are all destroyed, the `Point` will be cleaned up. `shared_ptr<Point>` can be copied, unlike `unique_ptr<Point>`. This is very similar to Python's behaviour. However, do not forget that unlike in Python, there will be no machinery to break reference cycles.

Comment: -1 - For incorrectly stating that Point* p creates a memory leak, double delete or heap corruption in your program. It only does that if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: If you don't get it *perfectly correct every single time with absolutely no help from your compiler*. And it is extremely common for this to happen. There is a reason that smart pointers are dominant and it's because `new` does indeed cause such problems, often. Even people who know what they are doing get it wrong when you do it 20,000 times. Oh, and don't forget all that repeated code with exceptions and all that *fun*.

Comment: It's not that extremely common at all really. You need to hang out with better programmers.

Comment: The OP just wants a little clarification about C++ syntax, not a silly rant about some guy's One True Way to code.

Comment: DeadMG, it seems as though every time there is a question about C++, you're always here to tell us about smart pointers. What is amazing is that the content of the question is irrelevant! You just tell people about smart pointers and move on. So now let me say it: *We know. We get it. RAII is the best thing since sliced bread.* Just answer his question and move on. After a while it just starts looking pathetic.

Comment: Yes. Answer the question first. Then add a follow up about better technique. The OP is obviously not a C++ programmer he does not need to wade threw the minutia first.

Comment: Probably because I'm the one who has to help him when he writes thousands of lines of shit. And then he's the one who has to go and re-write all the work he did since he encountered your ... ahem ... *generous* answer, teaching him to write that shit. If you take five seconds to stop and think about the impact of your answer, then it's just blind to go ahead as if there's nothing wrong with this. You may as well go describing `goto` to some guy and then pretend that the resulting spaghetti rubbish is none of your fault.

Comment: @DeadMG, sure thing cowboy. Go write your super awesome code on your own. The kind of people you work with are probably mere mortals in comparison.

Comment: @DeadMG: While I agree that it can cause problems and I also admit that I have run into it a few times. However, in 20+ years of development, I think this issue has only arisen (past the code and unit testing stage) less than 10 times in my career. People who program in C++ know this is an issue and tend to make sure they account for it, so yes, it can be an issue but generally isn't. So my criticism is not for your claiming that it is potentially a problem, but for you claiming that it is automatically going to be a problem.